# Why pow() return 999... in C++

Tags: c++, return, pow

why does `pow()` return 99... numbers?

When I write own my own `Power` function it works.
Can somebody explain this to me?

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       int bin = 0;
       int tab[3];
       tab[0]=1;
       tab[1]=0;
       tab[2]=1;
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
       {
          bin = bin + tab[3-1-i]*pow(10,3-1-i);
          cout << bin << endl;
       }

       return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't: http://ideone.com/73TdKP.

Comment: Yes it does.
[link]http://i.imgur.com/ILpDIj7.png[/link]

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think it may be a reasonable question (even if a dupe) and indeed it looks like it may happen

Comment: @Cezikos see the dupe